# Dashcode question - OnClick image to fullscreen?

Tags: image, dashcode

I have a web app I'm building in Dashcode, currently every thing is working as advertised. I'm using the browser template and was able to modify it a bit, got the xml working to connect images and their description. Now I want to add a simple OnClick event that sends the image to fullscreen but I can't find any documentation for that. I'm pretty sure this is easily done so I'm missing something here? Any help greatly appreciated.

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Taking over the screen is a bit complicated (if your talking about a full screen experience like youtube), but full screen in the browser window is defiantly possible. The simplest method is to have the click event open a link to the image location. This would load the image in full resolution in the browser window. A more elegant approach would be to load the image url into the source of a image dashcode object. and have that objects visibility only appear overs the whole web app when the Oncick event occurs. If you are talking about a built in function in dashcode to achieve a full screen/browser image, your out of luck.

Comment: Great thank you for responding, it is very hard to get any information on DC. To bad there aren't more function in DC, I'm not JS expert(or novice). I'm afraid writing my own function would take a day and a night. But I like the idea if loading the image using a URL call(done that with the widget). I'm actually thinking of on mouseover/touch call the image url. But would it be faster to get the image from a relative path or cache?